# How to assign a view controller as UINavigationController's first item inside a custom class but not in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I want to create a view controller, `HomePageViewController`, that is at the top of the `navigation` hierarchy. But I don't want to create it inside `AppDelegate`. And I have another `viewcontroller`, `MainViewController`, that allocates and inits `HomePageViewController`.

So, at first I create `MainViewController` inside `AppDelegate` and then inside `MainViewController` I create `HomePageViewController`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why should you want to create MainViewController you can create a class that subclasses the NSObject which should handle the creation of your HomePageViewController?

Comment: You can edit the navigation view hierarchy. Just use viewControllers property of the navigation controller. This will basically return you a array of the view controller just replace the array with an array containing the HomePageViewController as the only element.

Comment: Apologies for not making my question clear and detailed. I have MainViewController that holds two view controllers, MenuViewController and HomePageViewController. The HomePageViewController contains UITableView. Now whenever the user select any row of the table view, the HomePageViewController should push itself into the navigation hierarchy, and a detail view opens. The problem is that I have to keep the MenuViewController as it is. So basically the HomePageViewController is the only thing that changes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create navigation controller with `- (id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController` where `rootViewController` is yours `HomePageViewController`
2. Present navigation controller with `- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion`

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code:

```
HomePageViewController *controller=[HomePageViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController=[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:Nil];
```